# C# OleDB SQL Insert Command

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb

I am trying implement a SQL `INSERT` command into my MS Access database using C# with Visual Studio 2012.

But after that, when I open my Access database, there is no updates even the `insert` command can be successfully created by showing the success pop-up window after `executeNonQuery()`

Would you please tell me how to make this insert into SQL command work?

This is my code

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO STUDENT(CHI_NAME, ENG_NAME, NICK_NAME, 
                                        BD_YYYY, BD_MM, BD_DD,
                                        HOME_TEL, NO_OF_CHILD, PARENT_EMAIL,
                                        SEC_EMAIL, STUDENT_ADDR, DISTRICT, 
                                        MOTHER_NAME, MOTHER_TEL, MOTHER_OCCU, 
                                        FATHER_NAME, FATHER_TEL, FATHER_OCCU,
                                        E_NAME, E_TEL, E_RELATIONSHIP, REMARKS) 
                    VALUES(@NEW_CHI_NAME, @NEW_EN  G_NAME, @NEW_NICK_NAME, 
                           @NEW_BD_YYYY, @NEW_BD_MM .....);"

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NEW_CHI_NAME", chi_name);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NEW_ENG_NAME", eng_name);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NEW_NICK_NAME", nick_name);            
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NEW_BD_YYYY", bd_year);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NEW_BD_MM", bd_month);
....

cmd.Connection = connection;
connection.Open();
cmd.Transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
int rows= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

if(rows > 0)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Insert New Client Success!");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Insert New Client Failed!"); 
}

cmd.Transaction.Commit();
connection.Dispose();
connection.Close();
```

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to show your connection string also.

Comment: Also: I would **commit** the transcation first, **before** showing a message box!

Comment: Do you have more than one copy of the Access DB? From your explanation, it is most likely you are updating a different database than the one you're verifying. As ethron10 suggests, check your connection string

Comment: You should .Close() the connection before you .Dispose() it.

Comment: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\KidSquare_1.0.4.accdb;Persist Security Info=True"

The database is put into the project file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Solution Explorer`, right click your Access file, choose `Properties`, and set `Copy To Output Directory` to `Copy if Newer`

Comment: Is the problem of not getting the update caused by the authority to access ?

Comment: No, the problem is because everytime you debug your app, a copy of your Access database is copied to the projectFolder\bin\debug folder. All change happen to that file, so your original Access won't show anything. What's more, since everytime you debug the database is overwritten, you won't see the change between debugging. However, if you open the database inside projectFolder\bin\debug while not debugging, you'll see the change. A more permanent way instead of copy newer will be simply deploying your app.

Comment: Does it implies that the changes of DB are committed into the DB stored in the debug file rather than the DB in the project folder? It seems that the DB dragged into the project folder only used for DB connection and applying the table schema

Comment: Yup. Sorry if my wording are confusing. And to populate the initial data too.

Comment: That's OK. Thank you so much

Am I necessary to set thread for beginning and committing the DB transaction for insert/update/ delete if the application is only used for one computer , N users ?

Comment: Will they use the app simultaneously? If so, commit after every operation, otherwise, you can delay until the user exit/logout the app.

Comment: can we retrieve the inserted record in the DB after the insert. It seems that new database can be created after DB connection

Comment: Of course we can retrieve them. Or do you mean you want to retrieve only those from particular users? Either way, if you deploy the app, you don't have to worry about the database getting overwritten, all change will persist. The overwrite behavior only exist in debugging via VS

Comment: Oh I see~ Thank you so much , Martheen

Comment: Anyway but how to affect the Access DB attached in the project file if I choose not to show the effect on the bin/debug?

Comment: Remove the Access DB from solution explorer (try copying it first to other place), then Add new data source, select that DB, but don't select "copy to local/solution"

Answer (score 0):

Go to the debug directory, you will find you accdb file copied there. Open it and verify.